# Función para obtener números anteriores a un valor

Tags: array, r, funcion

Me gustaría saber si hay alguna función que devuelva un vector con los números anteriores de un número dado:
Ejemplo de función:

```
fun(5)
```

y devuelva:

```
[1] 4 3 2 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay al menos dos formas de generar secuencias en R, la clásica con la notación `desde:hasta`, por ejemplo

```
> 1:5
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

Que también permite secuencias descendentes:

```
> 5:1
[1] 5 4 3 2 1
```

La otra es por medio de alguna de las funciones que generan sequencias, por ejemplo:

```
> seq(from=5, to=1)
[1] 5 4 3 2 1
```

Ahora bien, teniendo en cuenta lo anterior, puedes implementar alguna de estas opciones:

```
func <- function(n) (n:1)[-1]
func <- function(n) (n-1):1
func <- function(n) (seq(from=n-1, to=1))
```